# LINQ - Where clause with Boolean method

Tags: c#, linq, boolean, where-clause

I have following classes. My objective is to filter Components on the basis of productTypeField and downloadSpeedField. I have a list `lstFilteredComps` where I want to add INTERNET productType Component having downloadSpeed less than or equal to 5 only If Components greater than 5 exists. If all Components are less than or equal to downloadSpeed 5 then it should add INTERNET component with downloadSpeed less than equal to 5.

**Classes**:

```
 public ct_Component[] Components {
 get {
     return this.componentsField;
 }
 set {
    this.componentsField = value;
 }
    }

public partial class ct_Component
{
    private string descriptionField;
    private string downloadSpeedField;
    private string productTypeField;
}
```

I tried the following code but it removes components with downloadSpeed of 5 in all cases, how will I place a condition to check if downlaodSpeed more than 5 exists or not. That is, my code should remove Components only if higher is available or in other words `FilterInternetComponentLessThan5MB` should only be called when more than 5MBs of downloadSpeed components exist.

```
ct_Component[] Components = response;
foreach (ct_Component comp in Components.Where(c => FilterInternetComponentLessThan5MB(c)))
{
    list<ct_Component> lstFilteredComps= //add filtered components;
}
```

**FilterComponentLessThan5MB method**

```
private bool FilterComponentLessThan5MB(ct_Component component)
{
    if (component.productType != "INTERNET" || (component.productType == "INTERNET"
        && int.Parse(Regex.Replace(component.downloadSpeed, @"[^\d]", "")) > 5))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

I need a check something like:

```
foreach (ct_Component comp in Components.Where(Components.any(x=>x.productType == "INTERNET" && int.Parse(Regex.Replace(x.downloadSpeed, @"[^\d]", "")) > 5) ? true :  FilterInternetComponentLessThan5MB(c)))
```

Comment: `FilterComponentLessThan5MB` returns `true` if speed > 5, so it is really `speedGreaterThan5` and `Components.where(speedGreaterThan5)` returns those with speed > 5 instead of removing it.

Comment: Yes. my objective is to call `FilterComponentLessThan5MB` after checking something like `foreach (ct_Component comp in Components.Where(Components.any(x=>x.productType == "INTERNET" && int.Parse(Regex.Replace(x.downloadSpeed, @"[^\d]", "")) > 5) ? true : c => FilterInternetComponentLessThan5MB(c)))`

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for the `Any` method, which receives a private parameter, similar to the `Where`, but it returns a Boolean as when one of the items in the collection evaluates true for your predicate.

You would end up with something like this:

```
ct_Component[] components = response;
if (components.Any(c => c.DownloadSpeedNumber > 5))
{
    var newList = new List<ct_Component>();
    foreach (ct_Component comp in components.Where(FilterInternetComponentLessThan5MB))
    {
        //add filtered components to newList.
    }
```

Where `DownloadSpeedNumber` could be a getter or an extension method that safely parses the existing `downloadSpeed` field.

Keep in mind though that you would be iterating through the array in the `Any` method, so if you have a really large array you might reconsider using Linq and just go with a regular for and iterate it only once.

Comment: Basically, I wan to make the method call if my condition is true. So something like `if(downloadspeed > 5){ foreach (ct_Component comp in components.Where(FilterInternetComponentLessThan5MB) } else { foreach (ct_Component comp in components) }`

Comment: I believe that the `Any` would help you achieve that

Answer (score 0):

Given a couple of predicate functions:

```
bool FilterNotInternetComponentOrOver5Mb(ct_Component component) =>
    (component.productTypeField != "INTERNET") ||
    (int.Parse(Regex.Replace(component.downloadSpeedField, @"[^\d]", "")) > 5);

bool FilterInternetComponentOver5Mb(ct_Component component) =>
    component.productTypeField == "INTERNET" &&
        int.Parse(Regex.Replace(component.downloadSpeedField, @"[^\d]", "")) > 5;
```

You can filter based on any over 5 using:

```
var hasOver5 = Components.Any(c => FilterInternetComponentOver5Mb(c));
var lstFilteredComps = Components.Where(c => !hasOver5 || FilterNotInternetComponentOrOver5Mb(c)).ToList();
```